# Which locale related settings changes double quotes into "«" as I type

Tags: microsoft-outlook, keyboard, locale

Good morning,
I'm working on a Windows 10 computer with Belgian locale (French language), and constantly my double quotes seem to be replaced by "«" (opening) and corresponding closing characters. This just happened while I was typing a mail in MS-Outlook, but I believe it to be general. I searched in MS-Outlook help for "smart quotes" but there were no result, I believe it is a locale setting, but I don't know which one. In top of that, in front of a question mark, an extra space is added too, which I don't want.

Anybody knows where I can find those settings?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The option for Office is found in Word, menu
*File > Options > Proofing*, click the button
"AutoCorrect Options…", go to tab "AutoFormat As You Type".

The option name is
`"Straight quotes" with “smart quotes"`.

[image]

Comment: I have found it and it works fine, but you need to add that this cannot be found in MS-Outlook's options, you need to open MS-Word in order to see the "Proofing" tab in the "Options" menu (or do you know a way to make this visible?).

Comment: No, Office is funny this way.

Comment: According to my experience, we could also find the option in Outlook via File>Options>Mail>Spelling and AutoCorrect>AutoCorrect Options> AutoFormat As You Type

Comment: In Outlook 365 (as of 2022) this option is in File>Options>Mail>Compose Messages>Editor Options..>Proofing>AutoCorrect options